# How quadratic drag is incorporated into trajectory equation

Tags: derivatives

Given the following trajectory equation with gravitational force $\left(F_G\right)$ and drag force $\left(F_D\right)$:

$$m a = F_G + F_D = m g \hat{y} - b \left( \hat{x} + \hat{y} \right)$$

and letting $k=\frac{b}{m}$ you can seperate the above equation into $x$ and $y$-equations,

$$\begin{split}
x''(t)&=-k x'(t)\\
y''(t)&=-g-ky'(t)
\end{split}$$

My question is:  what is the math to go from $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ to $x'\left(t\right)$ and $y'\left(t\right)$?

Comment: For future reference, you shouldn't put \$\$ around everything, just around individual math formulas. Otherwise you get some really messed up formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tip

Comment: Are you sure this is true? It seems wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your equation
$$
ma=F_G+F_D=mg\hat{y}-b(\hat{x}+\hat{y})
$$
has been badly garbled.

If $\ \mathbf{i}\ $ and $\ \mathbf{j}\ $ are unit vectors in the horizontal direction of increasing $ x\ $ and vertical direction of increasing $\ y\ $ respectively, then the force of gravity on a particle is
$$
F_G=-mg\,\mathbf{j}
$$
and if its trajectory is $\ x(t)\,\mathbf{i}+y(t)\,\mathbf{j}\ $, its acceleration is
$$
a=x''(t)\,\mathbf{i}+y''(t)\,\mathbf{j}
$$
Your differential equations would therefore follow from Newton's second law,
$$
ma=F_G+F_D
$$
if
$$
F_D=-b\big(x'(t)\,\mathbf{i}+y'(t)\,\mathbf{j}\big)\ .
$$
However, I can see no interpretation of the $\ \hat{x}\ $ and $\ \hat{y}\ $ appearing in your original equation (even allowing for a minor typo) that would lead to this result.

Also, $\ F_D\ $ of this form would be [*linear drag*](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/lindrg.html), not [*quadratic drag*](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/airfri2.html#c2).

Comment: Thank you for this clarification.  This clears up the difficulty I was having with the paper I was using as a reference.  Thanks for you time and help.